# Android SDK Tools Rev.17 - onClick - Corresponding method handler not found

Tags: android, onclick, android-sdk-2.3

I updated Android SDK Tools to revision 17 and after I opened Eclipse I found a list of new errors in the 'Problems' view which weren't there before the update. These errors were in XML Layout files where I had defined the onClick attribute for buttons. On mouse-over the error message example:

"Corresponding method handler 'public void @string/timespanDefinition_btnSave_Click(android.view.View)' not found"

returned. I have already defined the corresponding method handler and the string representation for this event name. What is the cause and solution of this problem?

Some code:

XML Layout

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/timespanDefinition_tglVibration"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:onClick="@string/timespanDefinition_tglVibration_Click"
        android:saveEnabled="true" />
```

Activity which inflates XML Layout

```
public class TimespanDefinitionActivity extends Activity
```

{

```
// -- Attributes -- //

private long mRowId = -1;
private StringBuilder mBitWeekDays;
private String mTitle;

private EditText txtTitle;
private TabHost tabHost;
private TimePicker tmepkrStart;
private TimePicker tmepkrEnd;
private CheckBox[] weekDays;
private SeekBar skbrVolume;
private ToggleButton tglVibration;

// -- Class Events -- //

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.timespan_definition);

    initializeResources();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    // Get the time-span Row ID
    mRowId = (extras != null) ? extras.getLong(RVSUtilities.getDefaultPackage() + TimespanScheduleTable.KEY_ROWID)
            : -1;

    populateResources();
}

// -- User Events -- //

public void tglVibration_Click(View v)
{
    if (((ToggleButton) v).isChecked())
    {
        Vibrator vibrate = (Vibrator) getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrate.vibrate(1000);
    }
}
```

strings.xml:

```
<string name="timespanDefinition_tglVibration_Click">tglVibration_Click</string>
```

Note: The app is targeting Android 2.3.3 specifically Google API version 10

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is the cause and solution of this problem?

The cause is your use of a string resource for the method name.

The solution is to get rid of the string resource and to put the method name in the `android:onClick` attribute directly.

**UPDATE**: If the markers do not go away, right-click over the project, and choose Android Tools > Clear Lint Markers.

Comment: I changed the onClick attribute to: `android:onClick="tglVibration_Click"` but was all in vein because the error remained. However it seems like the error didn't update with the new attribute value. I therefore cleaned and rebuild the project and even tried closing and re-opening Eclipse but the error remained the same: "Corresponding method handler 'public void @string/timespanDefinition_tglVibration_Click(android.view.View)' not found" Any ideas?

Comment: @Kurt: No, I would have expected that simply changing the file would have cleared up your problem, let alone cleaning the project or restarting Eclipse. Are you using `tglVibration_Click` for more than one widget, where you perhaps still have the string resource for another one?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I am not using the same onClick event name for multiple widgets a search in the workspace for `tglVibration_Click` found only one result. I can't understand how this problem emerged after I updated the Android SDK tools.

Comment: @Kurt: Well, the lint utility definitely changed in R17, so I am not surprised that this issue appeared. I am surprised that your environment does not seem to recover after applying the fix.

Comment: @Kurt: I reproduced your problem and was able to clear the markers -- see the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Soon after update/install it shows errors. But re-running Lint corrects the problem.

Right Click Project -> Android Tools -> Click "Run Lint: Check for common Errors"

Answer (score 1):

i had this same problem...

1. check **tools:context=".MainActivity"** in your XML wheather its indicating to right java activity
2. Rebuilt or clean project from build--> clean project in top menu
3. make sure you have View in your function parameters **public void onclickdo(View view)**

hope this is help full