# Corresponding method handler not found - Android XML

Tags: android, android-layout

I came across this error when creating making changes to the XML of an existing project. This is what my XML looked like

activity_month_view.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.YearViewActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/month_view_prev_month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp"
        android:onClick="changeMonth"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

My Java class

MonthViewActivity.java

```
public class MonthViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_month_view);
    }

    public void changeMonth(View view) {
        //Some methods here
    }

}
```

The `onClick` property showed this error

```
 Corresponding method handler 'public void changeMonth(android.view.View)' not found
```

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9853240/6891637) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44918035/6891637) but they did not help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had made a mistake in declaring the context in the XML. I had used `.activities.YearViewActivity` but the `changeMonth` method was declared in a different activity, which was causing the error.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MonthViewActivity"> // Changed here

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/month_view_prev_month"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_left_black_24dp"
        android:onClick="changeMonth"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Changing the `tools:context` to the class of the calling activity fixed the error for me.

Comment: You should always check tools:context in that XML file, if the method you wrote in the .java file doesnt appear in the Design window's onClick field. This was very important pointer. thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can try this to solve the issue

XML in `.MainActivity`

```xml
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/numbers"
    style="@style/CategoryStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/category_numbers"
    android:text="@string/category_numbers"
    android:onClick="openNumberList"/>
```

**Java Code**

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void openNumberList(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, NumberActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

declare a method in MainActivity with the name of `openNumberList`. You don't need to define it in `NumberActitvity`

Answer (score 0):

We need to define our method outside of the another func. like below

eg :

//another func

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {      
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
}
```

//my func

```
fun show_toast_msg(view:View) {   

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Im focused.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```