# corresponding method handler 'public void registerUser(android.view.View)' not found

Tags: android

I created a register button that onClick invokes the registerUser method. I checked the tool.context in my xml file but there isn't an issue with that. My code does register but it gives a warning in the xml file. This is my first time coding in android so I am worried it might break something later. 
XML file:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SignUpActivity">
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/signUpBtn"
    android:onClick="registerUser"
    android:layout_width="246dp"
    android:layout_height="68dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordField1" />
```

Java file:

```
public class SignUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity{ // implements View.OnClickListener{
private EditText emailField;
private EditText passwordField;
private EditText passwordField1;
private Button signUpBtn;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailField);
    passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField);
    passwordField1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordField1);
    signUpBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpBtn);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();

        }
    });




}
public void registerUser(){
    String email = emailField.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = passwordField.getText().toString().trim();
    String password1 = passwordField1.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty()){
        emailField.setError("Email is Required");
        emailField.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        emailField.setError("Email needs to be valid");
        emailField.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (password.isEmpty()){
        passwordField.setError("Password is Required");
        passwordField.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (password.length() < 6){
        passwordField.setError("Password needs to have at least 6 characters");
        passwordField.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if (!password1.equals(password)){
        passwordField1.setError("Passwords must match");
        passwordField1.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
        {
            if (!task.isSuccessful())
            {
                try
                {
                    throw task.getException();
                }
                catch (FirebaseAuthUserCollisionException existEmail)
                {
                    emailField.setError("Email is already used.");
                    emailField.requestFocus();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    emailField.setError(e.getMessage());
                    emailField.requestFocus();
                }

            }
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are Registered!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770526/corresponding-method-handler-not-found-android-xml/47770527. If you haven't added `tools:context` or wrote wrong activity, AS will show this error.

Answer (score 2):

your `registerUser` method should have the following :

- Be public
- Return void
- Define a View as its only parameter (this will be the View that was
  clicked)

so the correct definition is:

```
public void registerUser(View view) {
    //do something
}
```

**Edited:**

Don't use two ways to add click listener at the same time, if you use XML ways, you should define a method like:

```
public void registerUser(View view) {
        //do something
}
```

and **delete** below lines:

```
signUpBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            registerUser();
        }
 });
```

If you add click listener using java codes, you should **delete**:

```
android:onClick="registerUser"
```

Comment: does it matter if I use view or not?

Comment: @MohidulEfaz you are welcome, could you accept or upvote my answer, thanks!