# what is the replacement for onclick ( depecrated ) in kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want use `android:onClick` to access the functions at `MainActivity` from `activity_main.xml` but it's deprecated. Is there another way or replacement for `onClick`?

Here the code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/btn00"
        android:onClick="click"></Button></LinearLayout>
```

and my function at MainActivity

```
fun click(view: View){
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show
    }
```

There is an error saying "Corresponding method handler 'public void click(android.view.View)' not found.

Comment: `findViewById(...).setOnClickListener {}` ?

Comment: Your problem can be about .show part it should be show() can you write it correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Corresponding method handler not found - Android XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770526/corresponding-method-handler-not-found-android-xml)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Thanks all for the help,

Turns out I place my function at the wrong place.
I'm sorry for the trouble.
Turn out it's just a petty mistake :D

Edit: Turns out i placed my fuction outside of the class

Comment: Could you explain "at the wrong place". I'm having trouble making the android:onClick work as well and I have defined the context.

Answer (score 1):

The XML error is because there is no context specified for your layout file. you can specify it in the root element of layout XML file as

```
tools:context="yourpackage.MainActivity"
```

This basically tells the XML to look for `click` function in `MainActivity`.

Other than that this code should run correctly, given that you have specified the correct XML layout in your `Activity` `setContentView`.
point worth noting is that there is always an option to do it
programmatically in your `Activity` `onCreate`

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn00)
button.setOnClickListener{
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

Comment: tools:context="yourpackage.MainActivity" already coded when the project construced. Still my layout XML cant find the function